# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException при некоторых кириллических символах

Tags: java

```
public class CLIENT_PATH {

    String PATH;

    Path Path;

    public void INPUT_PATH(){

        out.println("Введите путь");

        do {
            out.print("  ");

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            PATH = in.next();

            Path = Paths.get(PATH);

            if (Files.exists(Path)) {
                out.println("    Путь введён\n");
            }
            else
                out.println("    Ошибка");
       } 
        while(Files.notExists(Path));

        out.println(PATH);

    }
}
```

При вводе русских символов К(R), П (G), О(J), и М (V) а также символов ", № и возможно других выбрасывает исключение. Хочу подчеркнуть что при вводе символов # или $ и других исключение не выбрасывает. Как обработать исключения?

> Введите путь
>
> п
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
>   char < ? > at index 0: ?
>
> Введите путь
>
> м
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
>   char <<> at index 0: <

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "обработкой" ? В чём, собственно, состоит вопрос? Вы хотите, чтобы проверялись пути, содержащие эти символы, или же хотите, чтобы при вводе этих символов ошибки не было?

Comment: @peterSamokhin Убрать ошибки. Почему ошибка? У меня не может быть в пути букв к, п, о, м? Почему так обрабатывает что в выводе другие знаки?

Comment: Не все символы допустимы, например `/ \ : * ? " < > |` запрещены самой `Windows`. Сейчас попробовал у себя: русские пути тоже не распознаются, но ошибок нет. Уверен, эта проблема решаема. Можете попробовать через коды символов: `\u0000` и так далее.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin С запрещёнными символами понятно. У меня русские пути распознаются, но не знаю почему когда введён любой из выше перечисленных русских символов то выбрасывает исключение. Будто Windows вместо введённых русских символов принимает их за запрещённые.

Comment: То есть, какие-то русские символы не вызывают ошибку, а какие-то - вызывают?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Да, и я написал все которые вызывают в вопросе, в выводе пишет что распознались запрещённые символы как я понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вычислить все "плохие" символы, и почему они вызывают ошибку - я не смогу сказать, но вы можете попробовать следующий костыль:

```
char a = '\u0045'; // 'E' (буква латинского алфавита)
char b = '\u041F'; // 'П'
String string = a + ":\\" b;
Path path = new Paths.get(string);

// Папка `E:\\П`
// У меня выполнение проверки выдало `true` без любых ошибок
// Папка `П`, естественно, существует на диске `E`.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проверил для разных букв - любые русские символы не распознаются, и даже если папка существует, результатом проверки будет `false`. 
Но если попробовать так, как я написал выше - всё работает.
Коды символов можете посмотреть здесь: https://unicode-table.com/ru/
 Символ `U+0030` в `Java` интерпретируется как `'\u0030'`, например.
Чтобы обработать эту ошибку, вам нужно вычислить все "проблемные" символы и для них использовать `String.replace("что меняем", "на что меняем")`. 
Возможно, глупое решение, но точно сработает.

Comment: Это не то что нужно, в NetBeans кириллические пути работают кроме тех что в вопросе.

Comment: @ELe попробуйте вычислить, как я и сказал, проблемные символы и только с ними поступить так. Я пробовал через консоль, и там кириллица не воспринимается

Comment: @Я создал jar файл и при вводе в консоль кириллицы нету никаких ошибок. Такие исключения только в консоли NetBeans.